# karma error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngTableParamsProvider <- ngTableParams

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Here is my controller:

```
var myapp = angular.module('legalControllers', []);
myapp.controller('lemEl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'ngTableParams', '$filter', '$q', function ($scope, $http, $location, ngTableParams, $filter, $q) {
    $scope.list = function () {
        $scope.enrollmentPromise = $http.get('./ccs/enrollment/ActiveList').success(function (data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        });
    };
}]);
```

and my spec:

```
 describe('controller: lemEl', function() {
     beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
         scope = {};
         $controller('lemEl', {$scope: scope});
     }));

     it('check for list function defined or not', function() {
         expect('list').toBeDefined();
     });
 });
```

Karma throws: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngTableParamsProvider <-ngTableParams`

please any one help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try angular.module('legalControllers', ['ngTableParams']);

Comment: thanks @ Mikael Härsjö, then failed to controller ]instantiation.

Comment: Yeah u need to inject $rootScope as well, and then $scope: $rootScope.$new()

Answer (score 0):

First add `ngTableParams` as a dependency of your module

```
var myapp = angular.module('legalControllers', ['ngTableParams']);
```

Then inject `$rootScope` before the tests and use it when instantiating your controller.

```
  var ctrl;
  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('lemEl', {$scope: $scope});
  }));
```